# How to use python timedelta function

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I am using the below logic to calculate the average timedelta inside a python list.

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta


def entry_rate(entry_timestamps):
   entry_deltas = [d1-d2 for d1,
                d2 in zip(entry_timestamps[1:], entry_timestamps[:-1])]
   average_timedelta = (sum(entry_deltas, timedelta(
                0)) / len(entry_deltas)).total_seconds() if len(entry_deltas) != 0 else -1.0
   return average_timedelta
```

Here is the input to the function:-

```
entry_timestamps = [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 7, 36, 21), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 7, 40, 53), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 7, 45, 25), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 7, 49, 58), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 7, 54, 30), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 7, 58, 32), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 8, 2, 34), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 8, 6, 36), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 8, 10, 38), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 8, 14, 40), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 8, 18, 42), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 8, 22, 44), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 8, 26, 46), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 8, 29, 18)]
```

However, I am getting the below error.

> in prepare_llog(llog_pd)
>       288 
>       289     result_df['entry_rate'] =\
>   --> 290         result_df['entry_timestamps'].apply(lambda x: compute_entry_rate(x))
>       291 
>       292
>
> ~/miniconda3/envs/jupyter_21f8c25de0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py
>   in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)    4043
>   else:    4044                 values = self.astype(object).values
>   -> 4045                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)    4046     4047         if len(mapped) and
>   isinstance(mapped[0], Series):
>
> pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()
>
> in (x)
>       288 
>       289     result_df['entry_rate'] =\
>   --> 290         result_df['entry_timestamps'].apply(lambda x: compute_entry_rate(x))
>       291 
>       292
>
> in
>   compute_entry_rate(entry_timestamps)
>        49 
>        50     average_timedelta = (sum(entry_deltas, timedelta(
>   ---> 51         0)) / len(entry_deltas)).total_seconds() if len(entry_deltas) != 0 else -1.0
>        52     return average_timedelta
>        53
>
> TypeError: _() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Can anyone please suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the entire stack trace, not just the last line of it?

Comment: calling `entry_rate(entry_timestamps)` causes no error to me

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pandas like this:

```
S = pd.Series([datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 7, 36, 21), 
    datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 7, 40, 53), 
    datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 7, 45, 25), 
    datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 7, 49, 58), 
    datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 7, 54, 30), 
    datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 7, 58, 32),
    datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 8, 2, 34),
    datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 8, 6, 36), 
    datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 8, 10, 38), 
    datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 8, 14, 40), 
    datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 8, 18, 42), 
    datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 8, 22, 44), 
    datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 8, 26, 46), 
    datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 13, 8, 29, 18)])

S.diff().mean().total_seconds()
```

Output:

```
244.384615384
```

Where as your function, `entry_rate` returns, without errors.:

```
 entry_rate(entry_timestamps)
```

Output:

```
 244.384615
```

## Timings:

Using `entry_rate`:

> 5.16 µs ± 193 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Using pandas functions:

> 389 µs ± 22.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops
>   each)

Comment: strange. Is it something todo with Python or Pandas version?

Comment: @amitpanda I am using version 1.0.1 with python 3.7.3

Comment: I am using pandas 0.25.3 and python 3.6